# Not able to login in Drupal 7 CMS as admin

Tags: users

I am not able to login in my Drupal admin panel, i have tried to truncate sessions, watchdog and cache table from database, also tried to reset password from database directly, but there is no luck for me. Can you please suggest how can i login and what steps i need to follow ?

Comment: Check via browser dev tools, do you always get 404 status code?

Comment: Please, provide info about what you're using as web server (apache,nginx). It's a new website? What errors message are you getting?

Comment: Can you please provide some detail like What are you getting after login?

Comment: I am not getting any info just redirect me to login page.

Comment: What is the path to the "login page"? What is the HTTP response code for the redirect to the login page? What happens if you type a *wrong* password. Has it worked on the same site before, or is this a new site? Do you have modules installed that may interfere with login (e.g. LoginToboggan).This question is too skimpy on details to allow us to help you.

Comment: yes it was working before a week, but recently it stopped. I found a issue, I am not able get $uid in user.module file on line no. 2236, that means authentication fails for function user_check_password.

Comment: Check if anything in this list of typical things might help: - Check if you get the same problem using another browser. If with another browser it works, then it might be a cookie problem (delete the cookie in the browser where you have the problem). - Make sure "clean urls" is enabled. - Make sure the value of "base_url" is set correctly.

Comment: Add specifics to question. It is unlikely that anyone will read comments to discover the difference between your problem and similar problems that has already been answered.